# Загрузка отдельных таблиц из полного файла дампа MySQL

Tags: mysql, dump

Гугл не ответил.
Есть дамп базы данных MySQL в архиве порядка 10 гигов. Без архива около 80 гигов. Из всего дампа нужно только несколько таблиц. Разворачивать весь дамп - несколько дней.

Есть какойто инструментарий для того чтобы вырезать именно эти таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ зависит от многих факторов - в частности, от того, в пустую БД надо развернуть часть таблиц или БД с таблицами и данными, есть ли FK у этих таблиц (в обе стороны) и т.п.

Простейший вариант - создание в БД тех таблиц, которые **не** **нужно** разворачивать из бэкапа, с неподходящей для заливки данных структурой. Если в бэкапе структуры сохранены с безусловным пересозданием - дополнительно отобрать у текущей учётки право на их удаление. Затем развернуть бэкап. Все запросы по созданию и наполнению этих таблиц срежутся по ошибке (нет прав, несоответствие полей), а нужные таблицы нормально создадутся и наполнятся. После чего фэйк-таблицы останется тихо удавить.

**Дополнение от [Anton Shchyrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221228/anton-shchyrov):**

Создайте новую учётную запись для выполнения процедуры восстановления.
Дайте (GRANT) ей права на БД, и отберите (REVOKE) права на те таблицы, которые не должны обновиться. Затем аутентифицируйтесь этой учётной записью и выполните восстановление - данные лягут только в те таблицы, для которых учётная запись имеет права.

Comment: Идея супер! Так может просто отобрать права на запись в ненужные таблицы и не нужно будет их курочить?